# Spring mvc / security : excluding the login page from spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring mvc + security to build a simple web app and currently having issues with the login. I am not able to exclude the login page from the spring security if i want to secure /** (everything basically). This is how my config look like:

**spring.security.xml**

```
    <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/view_register.htm" security="none"/>
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/game" authentication-failure-url="/failedlogin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
public class LoginLogoutController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {

    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/failedlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";
  }

}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.errorblock {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
    <h3>Login with Username and Password (Custom Page)</h3>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Don't have an account yet.</td>
                <td> <a href="<c:url value="view_register.htm" />" > Register here</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to secure the whole app and exlude the login and the registration page. With my current config the whole security behaves very strangly. If i enter wrong credentials the

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
```

is called and from the other hand if i enter the correct username/pass the login failed controller method is called.

Found out that if i modify the

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

to

```
<intercept-url pattern="/game*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

and remove the

```
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
```

everything is working as expected. Its very strange and can't really figure out why this is happening.

**EDIT**

**Just created a tiny version of my sample project (maven) and uploaded to:**
[fileswap](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/y0bVuJ3yJ6/). 
Any help or suggestion will be really cool as i am still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert these lines:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
<intercept-url pattern="/failedlogin/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
<intercept-url pattern="/view_register/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
```

after `<http>`, and add `auto-config="true"` inside `<http>`:

```xml
<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/failedlogin/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/view_register/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/game" authentication-failure-url="/failedlogin" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

and remove:

```xml
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
```

I do not know what this line is for, but it should work without it.

See the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/anonymous.html) for details on **anonymous authentication** (the important thing to understand is that if an anonymous user can access a page, it does not automatically mean that an authenticated user can access it too).

BWT, `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` is a built-in role, but `ROLE_USER` is not, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436554/2842067). You need to make sure `ROLE_USER` is assigned to the user.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598609/2842067) explains why patterns should end with `/**`.

Comment: Just tried and working nicely! Thanks for this! I will just read the articles/links you suggested try couple of things and get back to you.Thanks, you saved me lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this configuration which allows anonymous access to these urls:

```
<http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/view_register.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/game" authentication-failure-url="/failedlogin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

When you specify the following:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/game*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

Only URLs like `~/game*` will be protected, leaving all other URLs unprotected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just tried your solution (with a small modification - just moved the /** to the bottom of the intercept-url chain) but still the same issue. After hitting localhost:8080/webappName i am redirected to the login.jsp what is cool. Even i dont enter any username or pass just hit the submit the method handling the /login is called and i am just redirected to the same jsp without any error. Of course with good credentials the error is displayed: Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
Caused :
Interesting and quite frustrating.

Comment: "When you specify the following:
<intercept-url pattern="/game*" access="ROLE_USER" />
Only URLs like ~/game* will be protected, leaving all other URLs unprotected."

Yeah i know, but if i have just /game* the login.jsp behaves correctly. If the credentials are wrong displays the error message as it should and if i enter correct password and username I can hit the /game. But with /** it behaves exactly in the oposite way. Tried couple of syntax variations of the spring security config and still the same issue. But yeah thanks for you answer anyway.

Comment: @shippi, can you add * to the intercept-url pattern for login and see like <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

Comment: @sasankad - still the same :(

Comment: @shippi, then try this <intercept-url pattern="/login*" filters="none"/>

Comment: End up in error: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate <http> element for the pattern you 
want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'". I am using spring 3.2.0.